# UseEffect hook not work well when re update data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a list of orders, I'm using FlatList to render them,
I have 2 main concepts should I have "Load More, Pull to Refresh"

In my case user can edit the order then pull to refresh to get the newly updated data, and another case for load more "pagination".

SO
Load more functionality work properly well, and gets the new data from the server and pushed to the state with the old data,

BUT pull to refresh not works, it's not updated the data when setState, although the function that gets data triggered, and I can see the updated data in the console, It just renders the old data!

Here's a code snippet.

```
const OpenedAppointments = () => {
  const [openedAppointment, setOpenedAppointment] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isFetch, setIsFetch] = useState(false);


 const loadMoreOrders = () => {
    if (currentPage <= lastPage - 1) {
      setLoading(true);
      setCurrentPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
      console.log('loadMore??');
    }
  };


  const getOpenOrders = useCallback(() => {
    let AuthStr =
      'Bearer ';

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: AuthStr,
    };
    Api.post(
      `/open_orders?page=${currentPage}`,
      {},
      {
        headers,
      },
    )
      .then((res) => {
        let last_Page = res.data.open_orders.last_page;
        let allOpenedOrders = res.data.open_orders.data;
        console.log('allOpenedOrders', allOpenedOrders);
        console.log('last_Page', last_Page);
        console.log('currentPage', currentPage);
        setLastPage(last_Page);
        setOpenedAppointment((prevOpenedOrders) => [
          ...prevOpenedOrders,
          ...allOpenedOrders,
        ]);
        setLoading(false);
        setIsFetch(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
  }, [currentPage]);
    
 // Delete Appointments
  const cancelAppointem = (appointmentID) => {
    let AuthStr =
      'Bearer...';

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: AuthStr,
    };
    Api.post(
      '/cancel/order',
      {
        id: appointmentID,
      },
      {
        headers,
      },
    )
      .then((res) => {
        setIsOpenedCancelModal((opened) => !opened);
        console.log(res.data);
        setOpenedAppointment((prev) =>
      prev.filter((item) => item.id !== appointmentID),
    ); // works very well
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const _refresh = () => {
    setIsFetch(true);
    getOpenOrders();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getOpenOrders();
  }, [getOpenOrders]);

  const keyExtractor = (item, index) => String(index);



  return (
    <FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListCon}
      data={openedAppointment}
      ListEmptyComponent={renderEmpty}
      renderItem={renderItems}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      ListFooterComponent={_renderFooter}
      onEndReached={loadMoreOrders}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      onRefresh={_refresh}
      refreshing={isFetch}
    />
  );
};
```

Figure out the problem

At first render I got 5 orders from API, If I update the first order then pull to refresh, I got the same 5 order again but order number one is updated
So in `getOpenOrders` function, it merges old orders with new orders so I can see duplicated orders first 5 order "old data"
second 5 order "updated data".

But I have other concepts for load more "pagination" so it's should I have the merged arrays to get new order at the next page "2" with the prev order in the previous page "1"!

So how can I fix this?

Edit Data structure response

```
open_orders = [
   {id: 14, status: "Cash", cost: "25.00", service_id: 11, vendor_id: 3, …}
   {id: 15, status: "Cash", cost: "25.00", service_id: 11, vendor_id: 3, …}
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your effect should listen isFetch

```
  const _refresh = () => {
    setIsFetch(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getOpenOrders();
  }, [isFetch]);
```

Comment: Hey, It does not work as expected! And another thing in useEffect i got this warning from linter `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getOpenOrders'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`
Also, I can get duplicated data as you see in the `Figure out the problem` section

Answer (score 0):

```
const [updatePage, setUpdatePage] = useState(1)
const [isUpdate, setIsUpdate] = useState(false)

// call `setUpdatePage` when you edit the data
/**
*  const edit = (record)=>{
*     ...
*     const updatePageIndex = openedAppointment.findIndex((item)=> item.id === record.id)
*     const updatePageNum = Math.ceil(updatePageIndex/openedAppointment.length)
*     setUpdatePage(updatePageNum)
*     setIsUpdate(true)
*  }
*  
**/
const getOpenOrders = useCallback(() => {
    const pageNum = isUpdate ? updatePage : currentPage
    let AuthStr =
      'Bearer ';

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: AuthStr,
    };
    Api.post(
      `/open_orders?page=${pageNum}`,
      {},
      {
        headers,
      },
    )
      .then((res) => {
        let last_Page = res.data.open_orders.last_page;
        let allOpenedOrders = res.data.open_orders.data;
        ...
        if(openedAppointment.length > 0) {
          const newOpenedOrders = openedAppointment.map((item)=>{
             const target = allOpenedOrders.find(ele=> ele.id === item.id) || []
             return {
              ...item,
              ...target,
             }
          })
          setOpenedAppointment(newOpenedOrders);
        } else {
          setOpenedAppointment(allOpenedOrders)
        }
        setIsUpdate(false)
        ...
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('err', err));
  }, [currentPage]);
```

Comment: Hey!
At first render `openedAppointment` it's empty so how we use .map() in this case?

Comment: I guess when I calling `loadMoreOrders` it's increment the current page and based on it `getOpenOrders` fetching again and replacing the exit data in a flat list or something

Comment: actually I guess when you update the `data`, the got the data isn't the one which you edit

Comment: I know what the problem is here.  for example `currentPage` is 2, but you changed the 1st page's `data` so when you get the data from server, you can't get the new 1st  page's data

Comment: At first render data updated will when I want to edit first order in the first 5 orders in the current page 1, when I scroll to down it's should get the orders from next page "2" it's just replaced the first 5 orders except the first one still exist I guess 
other things when I re-update the first order and pull to refresh again I can't see the new updated " I know maybe you feel it's complex" please check [this](https://imgur.com/CuXtGnU) screenshot maybe will help!

Comment: hmm, let say current page "1" and without calling any load more functionality,
I want to update the first order, then make a pull to refresh, well? 
i can see the updated data,
**But** if I scroll down to calling load more function, it's should add first 5 orders from page 1 with the next 5 order on page 2,
But here it just renders the first 5 orders from page num 1 
And if I want to update any order then pull to refresh i can't see the updated data also 

Comment: Hey, you mean to add the rest of the code you added "Commented code" in the Edit order function? or just call `setUpdatePage`, I'm a little confused.

Comment: Sadly, It already edits the current order in first page,But in next page "2" not merge his orders with page "1" orders, I don't know why!
Also,
if I want to pull to refresh "without edit any orders" i can't get the new orders from server whether im in first page "1"!